# Matlab's fitrm function must have full column rank

Tags: matlab, matrix, regression, anova

Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to create a repeated measures model. I have a table with several response variables and several predictor variables.  I created a model using Wilkinson notation then passed my table with the model to fitrm.

```
mdl = fitrm(t,model);
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Error using RepeatedMeasuresModel.fit (line 1331)
The between-subjects design must have full column rank.

Error in fitrm (line 67)
s = RepeatedMeasuresModel.fit(ds,model,varargin{:});
```

What exactly does this error mean? When I change my model to 'response ~ 1' (in addition to a few others I have found) fitrm runs just fine.  I am fairly certain that my problem then has to be either with my formulation of the model, or (what I think is the problem) there is something wrong with my table.

The error itself hints to me that the rank of my table (if I were to convert to a matrix) is not full.  However, I have checked to make sure that neither my rows nor my columns are linearly independent.  In particular, I isolated two features, lets call them x and y, that when present give me the above error.  When I use either

```
model = 'response ~ y'  %or
model = 'response ~ x'
```

I get no error.  When I use

```
model = 'response ~ y + x
```

I get the above error.  y and x are linearly independent.  What could possibly be going on here?

Note, I cannot provide much more information than what I have already provided because of the nature of the data and model (medical data).

Edit:

A majority of my features are categorical numbers.  For example x may be 1,2, or 3 where the values of x are categorical.  I determined the the linear independence of my features by treating all predictors as numerical values.  My thought is if they are linearly independent in numerical form, they will certainly be so when represented in a different format; for example ASCII.  However, it maybe possible that the binary representations for two feature sets are linearly dependent.  I consider this highly unlikely though considering the size of my dataset.

When I ran the my code treating all categorical variables as numeric variables I did not receive an error.  This may mean that this is a internal matlab error.  Could it be possible that my features are linearly dependent when represented as either strings, categorical, or nominal values?  (these are the ways I have attempted to classify my categorical variables to test if this was indeed the problem;the matlab wiki indicates that these variable types are all treated equally as categorical variables).

Comment: have you tried reading this: **http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitlm.html**?

Comment: yes. fitlm is used to predict a single response variable.  I have serval response variables that I would like to predict.  I could use fitlm on every response variable that I would like to predict, but that would be cumbersome.  This is why I am trying to use a repeated measures model.